# Duplicating fields in SAS --- Use RETAIN statement?

Tags: sas, retain

I am trying to do the following.

I want this:

ID   Antibiotic1        Antibiotic2
1              1              .
1              .              .
1              .              2
1              .              .
2              .              1
2              3              .
2              .              .
3              1              .
3              .              2

To turn into this:

ID   Antibiotic1        Antibiotic2
1              1              2
1              1              2
1              1              2
1              1              2
2              3              1
2              3              1
2              3              1
3              1              1
3              2              2

Any ideas?

THANK YOU!!

Comment: It would be helpful if you can describe in words how to turn what you have into what you want. It's not clear from your post.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for something like this.  Note that below I initialized the default antibiotic values to 55 just so it stood out, but you probably want to change this to 2 for the example you gave above.

```
data antibiotics;
  input id anti1 anti2;
datalines;
1 1 .
1 . .
1 . 2 
1 . . 
2 . 1 
2 3 . 
2 . . 
3 1 .
3 . 2
;
run;

data antibiotics2;
  set antibiotics;
  retain prev_anti1 prev_anti2 55;

    if anti1 = . then do;
      anti1 = prev_anti1;
    end;
    if anti2 = . then do;
      anti2 = prev_anti2;
    end;

  prev_anti1 = anti1;
  prev_anti2 = anti2;

  drop prev:;
run;

proc print data=antibiotics2;
run;
```

The output is:

```
Obs    id    anti1    anti2

1      1      1        55
2      1      1        55
3      1      1         2
4      1      1         2
5      2      1         1
6      2      3         1
7      2      3         1
8      3      1         1
9      3      1         2
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're just randomly imputing the missing values based on factors you observed in the dataset. A wrinkle might be to consider whether you want these imputations to depend on the frequency in which they occur in the dataset. For instance, if you have 80% 1s in the non-missing data, do you want to generate 1 with probability 0.8 in the missing data?

You might want to read up on PROC SURVEYSELECT which is good for simulating draws from the sample of observed data. It may be necessary to transpose the dataset into a fixed width data frame first using PROC TRANSPOSE so that it's a long dataset and not a wide one. Then you will have only one column with missing data.